# Docker throwing Invalid Reference format exception when using volume mount

Tags: docker

> Engine: 18.09.2
>
> OS: Windows 10 Professional
>
> Docker Desktop V. 2.0.3 (31259)

When using the `-v` parameter to mount certain files in the container, I get the following exception:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format.

My Powershell script:

```
    docker run -d --name "kentucky_api" -p 83:83 -p 81:81 -e DB_ADDRESS="10.27.0.1" 
-v "J:\Docker\Folder\Configs\project\Public\":"C:\inetpub\publicapi\app_data\configs" 
-v "J:\Docker\Folder\Configs\project\Internal":"c:\inetpub\internal\app_data\configs" company.azurecr.io/project/repo:2019.04.16.15
```

Comment: try with: -v "J:\Docker\Folder\Configs\project\Public\:C:\inetpub\publicapi\app_data\configs", remove the double quotes before and after the `:`

Comment: You were right. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: If backslash is an escape in your shell, then `\":"` is only a single `"` to the shell, the first one may be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabio is correct. By removing the `"` between `:`, I was able to get this to work.

Updated Script:

```
docker run -d --name "kentucky_api" -p 83:83 -p 81:81 -e DB_ADDRESS="10.27.0.1" 
-v "J:\Docker\Folder\Configs\project\Public\:C:\inetpub\publicapi\app_data\configs" 
-v "J:\Docker\Folder\Configs\project\Internal:C:\inetpub\internal\app_data\configs" company.azurecr.io/project/repo:2019.04.16.15
```